# Image copies itself when zoom-in and zoom-out on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a minor problem with using custom image on google maps. When click zoom-in or zoom-out image count changes.

Anyone can give me idea?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLzbw4xz/1)

Comment: [edit] your question to add any missing information. It would be helpful to indicate what research you have done as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should related the dimension of the map to the zoom level

```
   myZoom= map.getZoom();

   tileSize: new google.maps.Size(myZoom*256, myZoom*256),
```

Because the number of tile x zoom displayed  change

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this tiles?

Comment: The tile are the part of map that google maps use for map visualization .. you can't avoid the use of tyle .. (the tyle used  or not are the map images) you use the map scaffolding for your images .. but also your images is based on tiles)

Comment: Okay, i got it how tiles works. But still can't figure out how to disable multiplied images on zoom :(